1980s B movie about an American girl and a Scottish guy
When I was living in Ukraine in 1994, I saw a movie dubbed into Russian, in the theatre. I think it was either a reeaally B movie, or it was made for tv. It's the story of an American woman who visits Scotland as a teenager, meets a Scottish, small town scruffy guy, they fall in love, she goes home to US.
The movie follows their love affair through the years. There is always an obstacle to their being together. One is married, then the other, one gets divorced finally....then at the end, in their 50s, they can finally be together and....yup, he has terminal cancer. It was so sad, but it stuck in my head, and I've searched and searched for it. The Russian title translated to Salt of our Tears.  Help??

This sounds like Salt on Our Skin (AKA Desire) from 1992 with Greta Scacchi and Vincent D'Onofrio (although the woman's not American):

A Scottish woman who attends school in Paris comes home for the summer and helps take in the straw, where she meets an attractive and simple man. They begin a torrid affair despite the differences in their lifestyles. He asks her to marry him but she refuses, and they continue their separate lives but also continue their affair through the years, loving each other despite their differences. 

They finally get together after her second divorce, but then the guy (Gavin) unfortunately dies of cancer. The film was based on a novel called Les vaisseaux du coeur. Here's a (rather spoilery) clip:



